# Database, query implementation

Tags: sql

```
I have a table named USERS:  
userID  userName
1       Foo
2       Bar
3       Foobar

I also have a table named MAIL:
mailID    senderID   recipientID   subject     messageBody
1          1           2            Hello      testtesttest
2          1           3            Hello2     test1test1test1
```

I have a form with fields From, To, Subject and Message Body.
My Question is, how can i implement a 
query in order to return an entry from MAIL table say entry mailID = 1 to fill the fields with the actual names contained in userName, the subject and the message body?

Comment: which is the foreign key in Mail? senderID or recipientID?

Comment: Do you want to know the `insert` statement?

Comment: No not the insert statement, just wanted to get viewable results from the database, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.mailid,
       m.subject,
       sender.userName,
       recepient.userName
FROM mail m
  JOIN users sender ON m.senderID = sender.userID
  JOIN users recepient ON m.recepientID = recepient.userID
```

Answer (score 2):

That will be (sans syntactic peculiarities of your particular DBMS)

```
select s.userName, r.userName, m.subject, m.messageBody 
    from mail m 
    inner join users s on m.senderID = s.ID
    inner join users r on m.senderID = r.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, got it now, the example was a generic one but i got the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
select username, subject, messageBody from Mail m inner join users u on m.recipientid (or senderid) = u.userid where entryid = 1
```

that should do it.